# Why would a member variable that is initialized in the constructor be undefined in ngInit in ionic / angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a modal consisting of a form that is bound to an instance of "Foo." During construction of the modal, foo is set correctly. I double-checked both using breakpoints and `console.log`. However, at any time after the constructor, `this.foo` is `undefined`.

--

EDIT:
I have found a solution, but my question still stands. My solution was to move my assignment of `foo` to `ngOnInit()` instead of the constructor.

--

Template:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>New Foo</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="foo.name"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <!-- etc... -->
    </ion-list>

    <ion-button expand="block" color="primary" (click)="create()">
      Create
    </ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

Component:

```
export class FooModalComponent implements OnInit {

  foo: Foo = new Foo();

  constructor(
    private modalController: ModalController,
    private navParams: NavParams
  ) { 
    const inputFoo = this.navParams.get("foo");

    if (inputFoo) {
      // this shouldn't matter, as foo would have to be truthy (not undefined)
      this.foo = inputFoo;
    }

    // logs this.foo as expected
    console.log(this.foo);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // logs: undefined
    console.log(this.foo);
  }

  close() {
    this.modalController.dismiss();
  }

  create() {
    this.modalController.dismiss(this.foo);
  }
}
```

Model:

```
export class Foo {
    name: string;
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the initialization isn't conditional. It is initialized in the field declaration as `foo: Foo = new Foo()`.

However, check out my edit. I found the solution, I just don't understand why.

Comment: Doh! Missed that bit, was only looking in the constructor's source. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In newer Ionic versions (probably 4+), data passed to modals as `componentProps`/`NavParams` get automatically assigned to corresponding class variables in the component to be presented. If you pass an undefined variable, the corresponding field will effectively get deleted. This happens after object construction, but before `ngOnInit` is called, that's why your workaround did the trick.

[Ionic 5 documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#passing-data) mentions `@Input` annotations for this, but the same seems to happen without as well, though I can't find any confirmation for that claim.

What you probably did:

```
this.modalController.create({
  component: FooModalComponent,
  componentProps: { foo: foo } // foo might be undefined
})
```

To avoid passing an undefined foo, you could do something like:

```
this.modalController.create({
  component: FooModalComponent,
  componentProps: foo ? { foo } : {}
})
```

Or, as you did, re-assign variables in `ngOnInit` as needed. On a side note, you might not need `NavParams` anymore in the constructor, since passed params are already assigned at this point.